# Batch SET /p works in cmd but not in DOSBox

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

I have this batch code:

```
IF [%1]==[] GOTO NoParameter
IF NOT [%1]==[] GOTO Parameter
:NoParameter
SET /p "Name= ASM file name (exclude .ASM): "
TASM    /ZI %Name%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
TLINK   /v  %Name%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
TD      %Name%
GOTO    End
:Parameter
TASM    /ZI %1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
TLINK   /v  %1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End
TD      %1
:End
```

It works great in CMD, but not in DOSBox, where I actually need it. The script is not paused at SET /p, and proceeds to the next commands, with null as the parameter, then stops at TLINK because the given parameter is invalid. If I input a parameter when running the script from DOSBox, the script works perfectly. Any idea how I can get user input like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOSBox doesn't support XP command extensions such as `set /p`, the developer [was against it](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=31751).

The only way to input a string of characters is to use another utility such as `string25` mentioned on that forum.

Comment: Thanks! I found string25 in [this FTP archive](ftp://ftp.cs.cuhk.hk/pub/simtelnet/msdos/batchutl/), and made got it to work. Now instead of `SET /p "Name= ASM file name (exclude .ASM): "`, I have `STRINGS Name= ASK ASM file name (exclude .ASM): ` and it works great.

Comment: sorry for necroposting but could someone send a working link? ftp doesn't work for me for some reason (it worked before)